# A error appeared in the code in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, syntax-error

I seem to have a problem with VS 2015.

It gets me the same error and i don't know why. I inserted below the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox2.PasswordChar = '*';
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void LogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Gigabyte\\Desktop\\apps\\WindowsFormsApplication3\\WindowsFormsApplication3\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Status FROM Login1 WHERE Username'" + textBox1.Text + "'AND Parola='" + textBox2.Text + "' ", con);
        con.Close();
        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows.Count==1)
        {
            Form2 ss = new Form2();
            ss.Show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Application form stopped at the line with the *sda.Fill(dt);* and shows me this error:

> Blockquote An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Blockquote
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'aa'.

Any help it is great! Thank you in advance!

Edit:
Problem Solved!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Please review your SQL statement and learn about using parameters to avoid SQL Injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `=` sign in your sql.

Additionally, you should be sanitizing your database inputs by using `SqlParameter`s, not concatinating a string. You're setting yourself up for SQL Injection if you continue with your implementation.

One other optimization is that the `SqlDataAdapter` automatically manages your `SqlConnection`, so you don't need to call `Open()` or `Close()` when using `Fill()`

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Status FROM Login1 WHERE Username = @username AND Parola= @parola";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textbox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parola", textbox2.Text);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: That's right. I missed the sign. And thx for the additional help! I will need it!

Answer (score -1):

Your string should be this I suppose :

`Status FROM Login1 WHERE Username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND Parola='" + textBox2.Text + "'`

You might have missed extra spaces ;)

Comment: Thank you for your comm but it isn't the problem. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you check the string, the equal sign is there as well :) Sorry I didn't highlight too.

Comment: @arobin: That's why you should place code inside a code tag. It is very unclear which " belong to the query and which aren't.